# Is it possible to apply css selector in lxml relative to a specific node?

Tags: python, css, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

Like, for example, I do with XPath for node `tag_line`:

```
for tag_line in grab.css_list('ul#navigation > li#main-li'):
    section_caption = tag_line.xpath('./span[1]')
```

This question is [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785864/python-using-xpath-locally-on-a-specific-element) but about using CSS selectors.

Comment: Have you tried `tag_line.css('span:first-of-type')`? (not exactly equivalent as it will search at any level below tag_line, as in `.//span[1]`)

Comment: @paultrmbrth, yes, there isn't such attribute as `css`

Comment: @paultrmbrth `tag_line.css()` - there is no such method . Neither there is `.css_list()` or `css_one()`

Comment: oh, you're using `grab`. I don't know `grab`.